# short php/mysql query to delete where two table select

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help to speed up my mysql query

my php code view looks like this:

```
$product = query("SELECT `id`, `productname`, MAX(NO) FROM `product_list` WHERE 1");
$count1 = query("SELECT  `products` FROM `count1` WHERE 1");

list($noproduct) = mysql_fetch_array($count1);

if (mysql_num_rows($product) > $noproduct) {

    query("DELETE FROM `product_list` WHERE `NO` > ".$noproduct.");

}
```

and mysql base looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `count1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `products` int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `count1` (`id`, `products`) VALUES
(1, 9);

CREATE TABLE `product_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productname` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `NO` int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `product_list` (`id`, `productname`, `NO`) VALUES
(1, 'product1', 1),
(2, 'product2', 2),
(3, 'product3', 3),
(4, 'product4', 4),
(5, 'product5', 5),
(6, 'product6', 6),
(7, 'product7', 7),
(8, 'product8', 8),
(9, 'product9', 9),
(10, 'product10', 10),
(11, 'product11', 11);

ALTER TABLE `product_list`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `count1`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `count1`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;


ALTER TABLE `product_list`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=12;
```

My code executes three queries every time the page is reloaded and I need to make only one query.

I think that it should look like:

```
Delete from product_list where (select product_list)  > (select count1)
```

Comment: What do you expect the table called `count1` to do? I think you have a severe misunderstanding of what your code is doing.

Comment: in the table "count1" is given a fixed value, and if the second table has a higher max(NO), the rows in product_list must be delete type something if( product_list.NO > count1.products){ DELETE ROWS IN products_list}

Comment: ofcourse produt_list.NO is MAX value from table, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this query:

```sql
DELETE FROM product_list 
WHERE NO > (SELECT  products FROM count1 LIMIT 1)
```

The addition of `LIMIT 1` is just a safety measure, in case you would have more than one record in *products*.

Note that there is no real need to first select `MAX(NO)`. It doesn't hurt to run the delete statement if there is nothing to delete. It will just do nothing then.

Comment: can you help me again? It is possible to do the same but this time with INSERT? It's about creating records in a similar way?

Comment: Sure, just ask a new question, and describe exactly what you need: the tables you have, the code you have tried and what the desired outcome is. If you want you can leave a message here when you've posted your question and I'll look at it.